# A Ring homomorphism problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

Would u please help me with understanding the end of this proof? I want to know that why J=R at the end of the proof. How we could get that? Do we use of “J contains ker(f)” for proving that? How?

Question : Let f:R—>S be a homomorphism of commutative unital rings.
Suppose that f is surjective. Prove that if P is a maximal ideal of S then f^(-1)(P)
is maximal in R.

Proof: If J is an ideal of R which contains f^(−1)(P) then J contains ker f and f(J) is an
ideal of S containing P. Since P is maximal, we have either f(J) = P or f(J) = S.
Since J contains the kernel of f, we have J = f^(−1)
(P) or J = f^(−1)(S) = R. This proves that f^(−1)(P) is maximal.

Comment: Compare your proof with the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198414/pull-back-image-of-maximal-ideal-under-surjective-ring-homomorphism-is-maximal). One of the answers is exactly what you have started.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank u so much! I appreciate your help :) I got it:)