# Let $\varphi : R \to R'$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. Let $I \subset R'$ be a maximal ideal. Then show that $\varphi^{-1}(I)$ is maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $\varphi : R \to R'$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. Let $I \subset R'$ be a maximal ideal. Then show that $\varphi^{-1}(I)$ is maximal ideal.

This question already has [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198450/711852), but I couldn't follow the hint. And I want to solve the question using correspondence theorem.

So As $\varphi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism so by first isomorphism theorem we have $R/ker \varphi \cong R'$. Now from the correspondence theorem, there exist a inclusion preserving Bijection map between $\{$maximal ideals of $R$ that contains $ker\varphi$ $\}$ and $\{$maximal ideals of $R'$ $\}$.

Now $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R'$.now how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Existence of bijections is not really enough, are you aware that you can write them down more or less explicitly?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I think I am not aware. Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

What @Matthias Klupsch is trying to hint at is that the correspondence you are quoting can be written down explicitly. I.e. the bijection is given as follows

$$ \{\mathfrak{m}\subset R: \mathfrak{m} \text{ is  max. ideal s.t.} \ker \phi \subset \mathfrak{m}\} \leftrightarrow \{ \mathfrak{n}\subset R/\ker \phi: \mathfrak{n} \text{ is max. ideal}\} $$ Let $\pi: R\to R/\ker \phi$ be the projection. Then the correspondence above is given by sending $\mathfrak{m}$ on the LHS to its image under $\pi$ an $\mathfrak{n}$ on the RHS to $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{n})$. Can you finish from here?

Response to comment: I corrected an error in the original answer. Maybe try again:)

Comment: As $R' \cong R/ker \varphi$, so $I \subset R'$ is maximal in $R/ker \varphi$, so from the correspondence theorem you mentioned, $\varphi^{-1}(I)$ is maximal suchthat it contains $ker \varphi$.

Comment: Is this complete the proof?